# Erro ao criar tabelas hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven

Estou recebendo a seguinte `Exception` ao criar as tabelas da minha aplicação:

```
Hibernate: create table UserConfig (id bigint not null, dateReg datetime, status varchar(255), accountActivationCurrentToken varchar(10000), forgotPasswordCurrentToken varchar(10000), loginCurrentToken varchar(10000), primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM
06-Feb-2018 15:00:22.208 WARN [http-nio-80-exec-25] org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl.handleException GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
 org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
    at br.com.wsbasestructure.dao.abstracts.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:35)
    at br.com.wsbasestructure.app.listener.AppContextListener.contextInitialized(AppContextListener.java:29)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
Hibernate: alter table Credit_Agreements add constraint UK_i7e61das28j9ypun0u5guh4ai unique (agreements_id)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:461)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1612)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1451)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:897)
Hibernate: alter table Credit_Assurances add constraint UK_jrxtlgawg0bf8a40tgt1p6fe5 unique (assurances_id)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:335)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
Hibernate: alter table Credit_Receipts add constraint UK_2knjb2x4ydv4thrskys915uv5 unique (receipts_id)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:536)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1983)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:891)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:795)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.execute(NewProxyStatement.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 57 more
```

Aqui está o meu `hibernate.cfg`:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mezinimi?useSSL=false&amp;useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123456</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">3</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">10</property>
        <mapping class="br.com.wsbasestructure.domain.impl.Notification"/>
        <mapping class="br.com.wsbasestructure.domain.impl.UserConfig"/>
        <mapping class="br.com.wsbasestructure.domain.impl.Change"/>
        <mapping class="br.com.mezinimi.domain.impl.Collaborator"/>
        <mapping class="br.com.mezinimi.domain.impl.Address"/>
        <mapping class="br.com.mezinimi.domain.impl.Customer"/>
        <mapping class="br.com.mezinimi.domain.impl.Credit"/>
        <mapping class="br.com.mezinimi.domain.impl.Document"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Estou utilizando `Maven`, esse é o meu `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
            <type>tar.bz2</type>
            <classifier>src</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Minha classe `UserConfig`:

```
@Entity
public class UserConfig extends br.com.wsbasestructure.domain.abstracts.Entity{

    private String forgotPasswordCurrentToken;
    private String accountActivationCurrentToken;
    private String loginCurrentToken;

    @Column(length = 10000)
    public String getForgotPasswordCurrentToken() {
        return forgotPasswordCurrentToken;
    }

    public void setForgotPasswordCurrentToken(String forgotPasswordCurrentToken) {
        this.forgotPasswordCurrentToken = forgotPasswordCurrentToken;
    }

    @Column(length = 10000)
    public String getAccountActivationCurrentToken() {
        return accountActivationCurrentToken;
    }

    public void setAccountActivationCurrentToken(String accountActivationCurrentToken) {
        this.accountActivationCurrentToken = accountActivationCurrentToken;
    }

    @Column(length = 10000)
    public String getLoginCurrentToken() {
        return loginCurrentToken;
    }

    public void setLoginCurrentToken(String loginCurrentToken) {
        this.loginCurrentToken = loginCurrentToken;
    }

}
```

Já tentei mudar o `dialect` mas não tive sucesso, tenho a mesma aplicação rodando em um `linux`, e funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Posta sua classe.

Comment: O log tem o erro: Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs .Reduza o tamanho dos campos ou altere o tipo de dados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro é esse:

> Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not
>   counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the
>   manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

Você está excedendo o tamanho máximo de uma tupla que, segundo a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html#row-size-limits) do MySQL, é de 65.535 *bytes*.

O espaço utilizado por um `VARCHAR`, segundo a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html) do MySQL, depende do seu comprimento (*length*) e do *character set* utilizado. Caso você esteja utilizando o *character set* `UTF-8`, por exemplo, cada caractere pode ocupar até 3 *bytes*, além de mais 1 ou 2 *bytes* que armazenam o tamanho da *String*. Isso significa que cada uma das suas colunas de 10.000 caracteres de comprimento podem ocupar até 32.002 *bytes*.

Para contornar essa limitação, você deve utilizar colunas do tipo `BLOB` ou `TEXT`, já que elas só ocupam um valor entre 9 até 12 *bytes* por não serem armazenadas na tupla.

Nesse caso suas anotações na classe `UserConfig` ficariam assim:

```
@Entity
public class UserConfig extends br.com.wsbasestructure.domain.abstracts.Entity{

    private String forgotPasswordCurrentToken;
    private String accountActivationCurrentToken;
    private String loginCurrentToken;

    @Column(length = 10000, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    public String getForgotPasswordCurrentToken() {
        return forgotPasswordCurrentToken;
    }

    public void setForgotPasswordCurrentToken(String forgotPasswordCurrentToken) {
        this.forgotPasswordCurrentToken = forgotPasswordCurrentToken;
    }

    @Column(length = 10000, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    public String getAccountActivationCurrentToken() {
        return accountActivationCurrentToken;
    }

    public void setAccountActivationCurrentToken(String accountActivationCurrentToken) {
        this.accountActivationCurrentToken = accountActivationCurrentToken;
    }

    @Column(length = 10000, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    public String getLoginCurrentToken() {
        return loginCurrentToken;
    }

    public void setLoginCurrentToken(String loginCurrentToken) {
        this.loginCurrentToken = loginCurrentToken;
    }

}
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou.